# Is it possible to create live chat customer support application with end to end encryption?

Tags: cryptography, chat, chatbot

There's a bunch of live chat customer support apps like Intercom, etc. that do not have end to end encryption between the customer and the support agent team.

I've researched this topic extensively and understand that there might be problems exchanging the keys between agent team and anonymous visitors on websites with live chat. But can't quite grasp the magnitude of the problem (I'm familiar on high level how this is done in iMessage by Apple).

Since this hasn't been done by any big provider yet, is there's any particular limitation that prevents this from working on this particular problem?

Is it possible (and how hard) to replicate what iMessage is doing in a domain with anonymous users and group chats (where multiple agent must be able to see messages from multiple anonymous users and other agents)

Comment: "there might be problems exchanging the keys between agent team and anonymous visitors on websites with live chat." This is a solved problem. See Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange. The question is why you would want E2E encryption for customer support rather than transport security like TLS. Typically would would want the company to have access to what their support staff are writing. Why would the company (or even the customer) want to hide the support conversation from the company? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The typical way to hide the data from the service provider is to use an on-prem solution rather than a cloud solution. But you can also do encrypted tunnels over TLS without requiring full E2E encryption. (That said, most support situations aren't going to be so sensitive that any of the parties would want to hide it from the cloud provider. People ask for support over Twitter all the time… The exceptions, such as when there are compliance requirements, are straightforward to solve with on-prem hosting. If there's compliance requirements, you probably need to record it anyway.)

Comment: (This question is better suited to security.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.)